# Elasticsearch.net Fluent DSL add list of sort

Tags: c#, sorting, nest, elasticsearch.net

I am using ElasticSearch Nest Fluent DSL and cant seem to figure out how to create a list of Sorts that the .Sort() accepts.

I have an array of sorts and i want to convert them to work with Nest a bit like you can do with Filters:

```
new List<Func<QueryContainerDescriptor, QueryContainer>>();
```

Any ideas?

I thought it would be something like:

```
var testSort = new List<ISort>();
foreach (var option in queryBuilder.Sort)
 {
testSort.Add(new FieldSort { Field = option.Key, Order = option.SortOrder == "ASC" ? SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.Descending });
 }
```

but .Sort() doesnt except it.

Thanks

Comment: The Sort usage tests might help: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/c9b8c1a9b2987484093184f41c2f64277c1b594f/tests/Tests/Search/Request/SortUsageTests.cs#L168-L224

Comment: Thanks but they only show how to do it for object initializer, not for fluent

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

```
 Func<SortDescriptor<dynamic>, IPromise<IList<ISort>>> sortList = st =>
            {
                if (queryBuilder.Sort != null)
                {
                    foreach (var option in queryBuilder.Sort)
                    {    
                        if (option.SortOrder == "ASC")
                        {
                            st.Ascending(option.Key);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            st.Descending(option.Key);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    st.Ascending(SortSpecialField.Score);
                }
                return st;
            };
```

Then in the query just add:

.Sort(sortList)